# unable to remove title bar?

Tags: android

i have a layout ,i want layout to be displayed on whole screen without title bar.
onCreate method of my activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);



    }
```

still getting gray title bar at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` at application level in the manifest file.

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the title bar by specifying it in the application manifest.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);// try  this
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
```